# Refactoring Liquibase changelog files

Tags: xml, database, liquibase

We are using [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org) for this project I'm working on right now, and all the changelogs are in one big XML-file. Unfortunately, this file has gotten WAY too big - and we want to introduce a "master" file, that includes the original file and any new ones.

The old structure:

```
/db/changesets-from-beginning-of-time.xml
```

The new structure:

```
/db/changesets/changesets-from-beginning-of-time.xml
/db/changesets/changesets-v.1.2.3.xml
/db/changesets/changeset-master.xml
```

The content of the `changesets-*` -files are simply changeset xml, while the `changeset-master.xml` file looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="...skipped...">
    <include file="changesets-from-beginning-of-time.xml" 
              relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="changesets-v1.2.3.xml" 
              relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Now, the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table in my database references the old files, and thus the old changesets are run again.

According to the [Liquibase documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html), each changeset is uniquely identified by the combination `[filepath/-name]:::[id]:::[author]` - which is less than optimal for me.

So my question is - how do I refactor the file structure without breaking my liquibase setup and emptying my database?

Answer (score 14):

There is also something called ["logicalFilePath"](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html) on liquibase which is described as:

> *Use to override the file name and path when creating the unique identifier of change sets. Required when moving or renaming change logs.*

Maybe that helps. 
If I remember it correctly this option allows to not include the complete file path to the identifier.

(This does not work for formatted sql files though. See [issue: CORE-915](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-915) in Liquibase Jira.

Comment: Good description of how to use logicalFilePath on this blog: http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/changeset-uniqueness-causing-issues-with-branched-releases-overlapped-changes-not-allowed-in-different-files

Comment: Bug for SQL syntax closed for v3.3!

Answer (score 9):

I like to point to old conversation between upstream and users:

http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/why-does-the-change-log-contain-the-file-name

I think that upstream arguments are weak and they make dumb decision to relay on full file path. Initial idea that you fix file paths via `CLASSPATH` but your request shown that this is wrong also.

Upstream developers suggest to perform direct update on `DATABASECHANGELOG.FILENAME` column to fix broken entries with full paths.

If you set hashes `DATABASECHANGELOG.MD5SUM` to `null` that will trigger hashes recalculation on the next LiquiBase run. You should do this because hash algorithm uses a file path as an input.

`logicalFilePath` can be applied to top level XML tag:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd"
                   logicalFilePath="legacy.xml">
    ...
</databaseChangeLog>
```

or may be overridden by each changeset:

```
<changeSet author="admin" id="fix-25" logicalFilePath="fix.xml">
   ...
</changeSet>
```

SQL syntax also have `logicalFilePath` attribute for top level file mark (implemented in v3.3):

```
--liquibase formatted sql  logicalFilePath:legacy.sql
```

and may be overridden in each changeset mark::

```
--changeset db-maint:tune-indexed  logicalFilePath:other.sql
```

To verify that settings have effect I use:

```
mvn liquibase:changelogSyncSQL
```

and review `migration.sql`. Corresponding `pom.xml` part:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sql/master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <propertyFile>${liquibase.profile}</propertyFile>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>

        <migrationSqlOutputFile>migration.sql</migrationSqlOutputFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

Liquibase has a "changelogSync" command, which can be used to mark changesets as executed in the database.