# How does liquibase interact with DATABASECHANGELOG?

Tags: liquibase

How does liquibase determine whether or not a change needs to be executed during a particular update? I thought that it was against just the ID column, but when I executed UPDATE command in liquibase against the same file of an already populated DB (via liquibase), if the file was under a different path, all changes registered as new changes. Does liquibase use the path AND the ID to determine if a change has occurred?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18785446/332248) might help. You can use "logicalFilePath" to avoid the full path of the file to be included in the id generation.
(I stumbled upon the same problem, when I moved by changelog files into a different dir.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Liquibase uses all three values to determine uniqueness. The reason filename is included as well is so that id/author uniqueness does not need to be managed across included changelog files.

Comment: The three values are id, author, and path.