# liquibase integration not interoperable between command line and application

Tags: command-line, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using liquibase since several years and it's extremly helpful for me as application developer to bring source code and database in sync, so thank you to all contributors for this tool.

During my daily work, I usually start liquibase from the command line in order to test the changesets and database operations. If everything is wired right, I start my application (Spring Boot) and the liquibase setup within the application performs all those sync steps. These setup works perfect unless my changelog file contains changesets with `loaddata` in order to populate data from CSV files into the database. Every application start fails with `liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
   change sets check sum`

The reason seems to be the different file locations for the CVS files mentioned in `loaddata` which are part of the checksum computation. If startet from the application, the changesets looks like this:

`classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml: classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml::loadDefaultRolePermissions::dominik`

But if started from commandline, there is no way to use classpath resources, the changeset infos looks like that

`liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog.xml: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog.xml::loadDefaultRolePermissions::dominik`

Both values differs and leads to different checksums.

If you look into liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.java, there is no classpath resource accessor used:

```
FileSystemResourceAccessor fsOpener = new FileSystemResourceAccessor();
CommandLineResourceAccessor clOpener = new CommandLineResourceAccessor(classLoader);
CompositeResourceAccessor fileOpener = new CompositeResourceAccessor(fsOpener, clOpener);
```

from [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.java](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java)

Is there any way to let liquibase be interoperable between command line AND application startup run ?

Thanks in advance
Dominik

Comment: Use `logicalFilePath`. Then the path will not be part of the checksum. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18785446/332248)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED by updating from liquibase 3.3.1 to 3.5.3